# ics file - Cannot open attached .ICS file in iOS7

Tags: ios, ios7, exchange-server, attachment, icalendar

My app creates an ICS file and send it as attachment to the email as type `mimeType:@"text/calendar"`.

Everything was working perfect in iOS6. If the device has iOS7 the attached .ICS to email does not open.

iOS6 - Opens attached file.
iOS7 - Not opening the attached file.

Windows 7 Exchange - Opening the file and works perfect.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm getting exactly the same problem. Googling shows some end-user issues with other apps -- like Outlook.

Comment: Also: Google's attachments are coming through OK. I tried copying their format, without success. I didn't copy their PRODID, but that might be the next step.

Comment: @EvanP. If you can post the .ICS file contents. I can look into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After debug and comparing sample ICS format, I found that iOS7 does not line multiline description part in the ICS file. I have changed the description to just one line (without any new line chars, see below). iOS 7 started recognizing the file and happy to open it. I am still researching how to add multiple lines of description, because it shows in email body of outlook on windows. Weird but at least know what was causing problem.

DESCRIPTION:My Sample Meeting

Answer (score 3):

Late reply, I know, but try changing the MIME type to

```
text/v-calendar
```

Just checked this on an iOS7 device and seems to work

Comment: still does not work for me. thanks for your help. looks like there is something else going on. The iCS file opens perfectly on devices with iOS 6.1.

Comment: further debug - When tried to open the ICS file is iPad mail app, it is logging message "Import of ics file yielded no events.". Looks like something is wrong in the file format which iOS 7 did not like.